# Creating a new Queue Manager and Queue in Websphere MQ (using C#)

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, queue, ibm-mq

I'm writing an application that uses WebSphere MQ for messaging. For my unittests (flowtests), I want to verify that I have put the right messages on the response queue.
I'm trying to figure out how to do this. My main obstacle is that I think it might be scary to clear a queue before I run my unittest, because the same queue might be used by another application. 
I thought a decent workaround would be to create a new queue manager and queue for my unittest and delete it after using it.

So my question is: Is it possible to create a queue manager and queue using C#?

Comment: Creation of queue manager and queues are administrative jobs. Creation of queue manager can not be done using an user defined application. You have to use the command `crtmqm <qmname>` provided by MQ to create queue manager. Assuming that you have an exclusive queue for your application, what methodology you plan to use to verify that a right message has been put on response queue?

Comment: Basically, in my application, I don't need to check whether I put the right message on the queue. It's solely for my unittests.

My plan so far was to clear the queue before unittesting, get all messages off the response queue after the test, and verify that the expected messages are on the queue, by using MQQueue.Get() and MQMessage.ReadString(MQMessage.MessageLength) and compare that to the expected value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For future reference and future people who want to create queues. I figured out how to create and delete IBM MQ queues (not queuemanagers) with PCF messaging. It is not very straightforward, but it can be done.

We have implemented it in a library and are using it to create and delete queues before and after integration tests respectivally. The most important part of code in this library is shown in the code sample below. Just add a reference to amqmdnet.dll and below code will create a queue and delete it.

```
string queueManagerName = "QM_LOCAL";
string queueName = "DeleteMeQueue";

Hashtable options = new Hashtable();

// This is a connection to a local server. For a remote server use 'TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT', 'TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_XACLIENT' or 'TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED'
options.Add(IBM.WMQ.MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, "TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_BINDINGS");

// For 'TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT', 'TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_XACLIENT' or 'TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED' uncomment the below
// string hostName = "RemoteServerName";
// string channelName = "SYSTEM.ADMIN.SVRCONN";
// int portNumber = 1414;
// options.Add(IBM.WMQ.MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, hostName);
// options.Add(IBM.WMQ.MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, channelName);
// options.Add(IBM.WMQ.MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, portNumber);
// options.Add(IBM.WMQ.MQC.CONNECT_OPTIONS_PROPERTY, IBM.WMQ.MQC.MQC.MQCNO_STANDARD_BINDING);
IBM.WMQ.MQQueueManager queueManager = null;
IBM.WMQ.PCF.PCFMessageAgent agent = null;
try
{
    // Initialize a connection to the (remote) queuemanager and a PCF message agent.
    queueManager = new IBM.WMQ.MQQueueManager(queueManagerName, options);
    agent = new IBM.WMQ.PCF.PCFMessageAgent(queueManager);

    // Create queue
    IBM.WMQ.PCF.PCFMessage createRequest = new IBM.WMQ.PCF.PCFMessage(IBM.WMQ.PCF.CMQCFC.MQCMD_CREATE_Q);
    createRequest.AddParameter(IBM.WMQ.MQC.MQCA_Q_NAME, queueName);
    createRequest.AddParameter(IBM.WMQ.MQC.MQIA_Q_TYPE, IBM.WMQ.MQC.MQQT_LOCAL);
    createRequest.AddParameter(IBM.WMQ.MQC.MQIA_DEF_PERSISTENCE, IBM.WMQ.MQC.MQPER_PERSISTENT);
    createRequest.AddParameter(IBM.WMQ.MQC.MQCA_Q_DESC, "Created by " + Environment.UserName + " on " + DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o"));
    IBM.WMQ.PCF.PCFMessage[] createResponses = agent.Send(createRequest);

    // Delete queue
    IBM.WMQ.PCF.PCFMessage deleteRequest = new IBM.WMQ.PCF.PCFMessage(IBM.WMQ.PCF.CMQCFC.MQCMD_DELETE_Q);
    deleteRequest.AddParameter(IBM.WMQ.MQC.MQCA_Q_NAME, queueName);
    IBM.WMQ.PCF.PCFMessage[] deleteResponses = agent.Send(deleteRequest);
}
finally
{
    // Disconnect the agent and queuemanager.
    if (agent != null) agent.Disconnect();
    if (queueManager != null && queueManager.IsConnected) queueManager.Disconnect();
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for this code sample, it helped me a lot. IBM doc is such a pain, it's so hard to figure out such basic features as creating a queue...

Answer (score 0):

Creation of queue manager and queues are administrative jobs. Creation of queue manager can not be done using an user defined application. You have to use the command `crtmqm <qmname>` provided by MQ to create queue manager.

I would suggest you ask your queue manager administrator to create dedicated queue for you. Only your unit test use this queue and no other user is allowed to put/get messages to this queue.

Comment: Well, I guess I'll have to go with your answer. I guess the next developer will just have to create the queues manually before unittesting the application. 
I was hoping to find an answer that would allow me to unittest my application on any machine with WebSphere MQ. I'll write comments in the code.